# Pandas data frame replace values in column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in data frame like this (an simplify example):

```
col
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

and I want to change the values like this:

```
col
a
b
other
other
other
other
other
```

I tried like this:

```
df = df.loc[df.col == ("a" or "b"), "col"] = "other"
```

but it does not work, I have an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'
```

Any advices?

Comment: your `df` somehow got replaced with a string value. that's why that error appears. and for the advice, see mosc9575 answer

Comment: Don't change your question after accepting an answer. I've rolled back the edit. It'd be more appropriate to ask a new question, though in this case, I see your question has already been answered in the comments on mosc9575's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that `df` is changing to type string during the process.

There exists a pandas function for this usecase, named [`pd.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.DataFrame.where).

```
df = df.where(df['col'].isin(['a', 'b']),'other')
```

Similar result avoiding `where()`:

```
df[~df['col'].isin(['a', 'b'])] = 'other'
```

Comment: About your solution, it is one problem. I probably I did not myself clear. I meant to change values into "other" only in that one column "col". Not in every column in row.

Comment: This is also valid for a single column/Series. Use `df['col'].where()`.

Comment: when I try: df = df["col"].where(df["col"].isin(["a", "b"]), "Other") I have got an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col'

Comment: You have to apply this to only one column. Use `df["col"] = df["col"].where(df["col"].isin(["a", "b"]), "Other")`

Comment: Thanks again for a quick reply! Works like it should.